# Y = base64(X) where X is integer - is Y alphanumeric?

Tags: math, encoding, character-encoding, base64

Additional details:

- X is any positive integer 6 digits or less.
- X is left-padded with zeros to maintain a width of 6.

Please explain your answer :)

(This might be better in the Math site, but figured it involves programming functions)

Comment: Is your question whether or not Y contains `+` or `/`?

Comment: I guess that's an equivalent question, yes

Comment: Looking for a Yes/No answer, was hoping someone might know off the top of their head.  I think the answer is yes, but not entirely familiar with the rules for the bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture from the [german Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is very helpful:

[image]

You see that 6 consecutive bits from the original bytes generate a Base64 value. To generate `+` or `/` (codes 62 and 63), you'd need the bitstrings `111110` and `111111`, so at least 5 consecutive bits set.

However, look at the ASCII codes for `0`...`9`:

```
00110000
00110001
00110010
00110011
00110100
00110101
00110110
00110111
00111000
00111001
```

No matter how you concatenate six of those, there won't be more than 3 consecutive bits set. So it's not possible to generate a Base64 string that contains `+` or `/` this way, Y will always be alphanumeric.

EDIT: In fact, you can even rule other Base64 values out like `000010` (`C`), so this leads to nice follow-up questions/puzzles like "How many of the 64 values are possible at all?".

Comment: Yep, phanx for the response +1